# Run as admin batch file command error .exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: batch-file

Error when running as Administrator :

> BackGroundJob.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Both the exe and the bat file is in same folder.

It run when I run it without run as administrator. But to install this .exe I need to install it as admin from same folder.

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO PRESS 1, 2 to select your task, or 3 to EXIT.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - Install BackGroundJob
ECHO 2 - UnInstall BackGroundJob
ECHO 3 - EXIT

ECHO.
SET /P M=Type 1, 2, or 3 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO INSTALL
IF %M%==2 GOTO UNINSTALL
IF %M%==3 GOTO EOF
:INSTALL
CD %cd%
BackGroundJob.exe install
GOTO MENU
:UNINSTALL
CD %cd%
BackGroundJob.exe uninstall
GOTO MENU
```

Comment: The initial working directory is not in your control. Change to the script directory, `cd /d %~dp0`, and then run `.\BackGroundJob.exe install`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can `where` the .exe file, get the path and do `%pathToExe%\BackgroundJob.exe`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not many information given, so here's a shot you may try.

---

### Actual File Location

It seems that `backgroundJob.exe` is not in:

- Any folders in the `path` environment variable
- The folder that the batch script is in

When using external tools, it is always ideal to check if the tool exists and is accessible.

#### How To Ensure File Exists

- Use `IF EXIST filename.ext`

  - This can check if the file exist, further preventing such error.
- Alternatively, use `for` and `where` to know where the file is

  - Loop through directories and retrieve the file path.

#### Current Directory

`CD %cd%` is not required since it just changes directory to the current directory. This line of code only comes into use when `%cd%` has be edited before, which is not recommended.

User eryksun has mentioned, maybe your current directory is not set to the batch file's directory. Consider adding `cd /d %~dp0`. `cd` changes directory, `/d` enables drive-changing, and `%~dp0` stands for the drive and path to the current batch script.

---

### Code insertion exploit

```
IF %M%==1
```

is very insecure, as the input can be almost anything, from alphanumeric characters to special characters. If `%M%` equals to a space, this happens:

```
IF   ==1
```

Command processor doesn't understand this.

Also if the input is

```
1==1 format D:\ &&
```

This will format your D drive.

---

### Exiting Script

`GOTO EOF` should be `GOTO :EOF`, as `:EOF` is a pre-defined label, and can only be accessed by `GOTO :EOF`. Otherwise, cmd will jump to an undefined EOF label, causing an error.

While `GOTO :EOF` works, I'd recommend to use the internal `exit` command.

`EXIT` exits the current command console. If you want to exit a subroutine or an additional script without closing the console, you should try `exit /b` instead.

---

### Hide The Command Output Of @echo off

You may consider to use `@echo off` instead of `echo off`, as the at-sign acts as the inline `@echo off`.